# Logging in to Stack Exchange if logged in to Stack Overflow via OpenID?

Tags: discussion, login, user-accounts, openid

I log in to Stack Exchange family of sites via OpenID.

So, if I login to, say, https://meta.stackexchange.com/, then I can just open the list of sites:

[image: meta.se.png]

... and I can just click on any of the "subdomain" SE sites (i.e. https://tex.stackexchange.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/), and be logged in there automatically too. So far, so good.

But, if I'm logged at say, https://meta.stackexchange.com/ and I try to click on a site from this list which is **not** a subdomain, such as https://superuser.com/ - then I am **not** logged in automatically, I have to enter my OpenID and authenticate again.

The same happens also in my usual workflow - usually I log in to Stack Overflow first, and then afterwards sometimes I need to log in to Unix/Linux; but if I click on Unix/Linux from the SO list of sites, then I am not logged in automatically, and I have to enter my OpenID and authenticate again.

Is it possible to somehow have me logged in automatically to other Stack Exchange sites - subdomains or not - if I am already logged in via OpenID to Stack Overflow?